# How to leverage Convex Optimization for Portfolio Optimization in Julia

Tags: julia, convex-optimization

I'm trying to use Julia (0.5) and Convex.jl (with ECOS solver) to figure out, given a portfolio of 2 stocks, how can I distribute my allocations (in percent) across both stocks such that I maximize my portfolio return and minimize my risk (std dev of returns).  I want to maximize what is known as the Sharpe ratio that is a calculation driven from what percentages I have in each of my 2 stocks.  So I want to MAXIMIZE the Sharpe ratio and have the solver figure out what is the optimal allocation for the two stocks (I want it to tell me I need x% of stock 1 and 1-x% of stock 2).  The only real constraint is that the sum of the percent allocations adds to 100%.  I have code below that runs, but does not give me the optimal weights/allocations I'm expecting (which is 36.3% for Supertech & 63.7% for Slowpoke).  The solver instead comes back with 50/50.

My intuition is that I either have the objective function modeled incorrectly for the solver, or I need to do more with constraints.  I don't have a good grasp on convex optimization so I'm winging it.  Also, my objective function uses the variable.value attribute to get the correct output and I suspect I need to be working with the Variable expression object instead.

Question is, is what I'm trying to achieve something the Convex solver is designed for and I just have to model the objective function and constraints better, or do I have to just iterate the weights and brute force it?

Code with comments:

```
using Convex, ECOS
Supertech = [-.2; .1; .3; .5];
Slowpoke = [.05; .2; -.12; .09];
A = reshape([Supertech; Slowpoke],4,2)
mlen = size(A)[1]
R = vec(mean(A,1))
n=rank(A)
w = Variable(n)
c1 = sum(w) == 1;
λ = .01
w.value = [λ; 1-λ]
sharpe_ratio = sqrt(mlen) * (w.value' * R) / sqrt(sum(vec(w.value' .* w.value) .*  vec(cov(A,1,false))))
# sharpe_ratio will be maximized at 1.80519 when w.value = [λ, 1-λ] where λ = .363
p = maximize(sharpe_ratio,c1);
solve!(p, ECOSSolver(verbose = false));  # when verbose=true, says is 'degenerate' because I don't have enough constrains...
println(w.value) # expecting to get [.363; .637] here but I get [0.5; 0.5]
```

Comment: you might get a better response if you (cross)post this to the optimization channel on [Julia Discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/c/domain/opt).

Comment: @KevinLKeys Thanks!  Done!